# How to deploy a theme.war file in liferay

Tags: liferay

I have a theme.war file, which I've placed in the server/tomcat/tomcat6/webapps  of liferay folder. When I start the tomcat server this war files create a theme folder. Now to deploy it what should i do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you deployed from a bundle (and assuming the bundle's base directory is `LIFERAY`) there should be a `LIFERAY/deploy` directory next to the `LIFERAY/tomcat6` directory. To deploy plugins to the Liferay portal server you should drop the WAR file in this `deploy` directory, not in the `webapps`. Plugins include portlet applications, themes, layouts, hooks and extensions.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what David stated (deploy through the "deploy" folder) you'll have to select your theme for the community, organization or just one page by selecting Manage/Page/Look&Feel when it's deployed to tomcat.

Somehow I had the impression that you expect it to show up immediately.

If you want to deploy directly to tomcat you'll have to build your theme in the plugins-sdk with "ant direct-deploy" - this creates a tomcat-deployable theme.